# Change Background Colors of Multiple Elements with the same ID using If Statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not that advanced with Javascript but looking to change the backgrounds of multiple ID's based on grabbing the elements number result, running it through my if statement to determine what background color it will get and adding that class to the elements class. Struggling quite a bit on this so any help would be greatly appreciated. No jQuery please.

HTML

```
<ul class="listview image-listview text">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <div class="in">
                        <div>Strength</div>
                        <span id="skill-badge" class="badge">38</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <div class="in">
                        <div>Agility</div>
                        <span id="skill-badge" class="badge">52</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <div class="in">
                        <div>Endurance</div>
                        <span id="skill-badge" class="badge">66</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <div class="in">
                        <div>Athleticism</div>
                        <span id="skill-badge" class="badge">49</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <div class="in">
                        <div>Resilience</div>
                        <span id="skill-badge" class="badge">26</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
.sb-default {
    background:rgb(66, 66, 66);
    color:white;
}

.sb-terrible {
    background:rgb(71, 0, 0);
    color:white;
}

.sb-poor {
    background:rgb(192, 64, 13);
    color:white;
}

.sb-avg {
    background:rgb(223, 167, 13);
    color:white;
}

.sb-aboveavg {
    background:rgb(204, 191, 8);
    color:white;
}

.sb-good {
    background:rgb(129, 194, 8);
    color:white;
}

.sb-excellent {
    background:rgb(90, 223, 13);
    color:white;
}
```

Javascript

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('#skill-badge');
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    var currentEl = el[i];
var class_name;

if (currentEl < 10) {
    class_name = 'sb-terrible';
} else if (currentEl < 25) {
    class_name = 'sb-poor';
} else if (currentEl < 50) {
    class_name = 'sb-avg';
} else if (currentEl < 75) {
    class_name = 'sb-aboveavg';
} else if (currentEl < 95) {
    class_name = 'sb-good';
} else if (currentEl < 100) {
    class_name = 'sb-excellent';
}else {
    class_name = 'sb-default';
}

el.className += ' ' + class_name;
}
```

=============================
Updated Javascript but for some reason it still wont add a class based on the number

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.skill-badge');
var val = parseInt(el.innerText);
var class_name;

if (val < 10) {
    class_name = 'sb-terrible';
} else if (val < 25) {
    class_name = 'sb-poor';
} else if (val < 50) {
    class_name = 'sb-avg';
} else if (val < 75) {
    class_name = 'sb-aboveavg';
} else if (val < 95) {
    class_name = 'sb-good';
} else if (val < 100) {
    class_name = 'sb-excellent';
}else {
    class_name = 'sb-default';
}

el.className += ' ' + class_name;
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Problem is `document.querySelectorAll('.skill-badge');` and in your html you still have `id="skill-badge"`. There is no class with the name `skill-badge`.

Answer (score 3):

Well I think you just misunderstood the concept of ID attribute. ID value for each element **Must Be Unique**. If there is duplicated ID value in a page, only the first one will be considered.

Therefore, you can give elements a common class and replace

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('#skill-badge');
```

with

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.common-class-name');
```

and there you go!

Comment: Updated the javascript but it still wont add the class based on the number result

Comment: @Fireal now your var `el` is a NodeList, you need to loop through it: https://gomakethings.com/es6-foreach-loops-with-vanilla-javascript/#the-nodelist-foreach-method

Answer (score -1):

The ID must be unique.

Just name them with classes and then move to js.

The simplest way for new JS developers without using any advanced codes.

Counting how many classes found with this name:

```js
    var number_of_elements = document.getElementsByClassName('your_class_name').length;
```

Now you get the number of classes you can now loop on them. For example:

```js
var i =0;
while (i<number_of_elements) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('your_class_name')[i].style.backgroundColor= 'red';
  //selecting each class and changing it's backgroundcolor
  i++;
}
```

Comment: While your general strategy is fine, the implementation is terrible.

Comment: i just wanted to say the technique in a very simple way that a beginner can understand